# How do I upgrade Apache 2.4 to 2.4.46?

Tags: apache, rhel7

Well, I already did it on one system and it didn't really work properly.  If I copy the old config file into place, starting I get the error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 65 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Include/IncludeOptional: Could not open directory /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d: No such file or directory

If I copy the directory from my old installation conf.modules.d, it fails with:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 65 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-lua.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_lua.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_lua.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

We had a lot of customizations in our old httpd.conf that would be very painful to reproduce.  What am I doing wrong?

Note:  On RHEL 7.8 and I built Apache 2.4.46's RPM's using rpmbuild.  It'll start fine using standard httpd.conf, but that has none of our customizations...

Thanks,
Eric